# Given a 4 digit PIN what is the probability of guessing the PIN in 3 tries.

Tags: probability

Since we have 4 digits there is a total of 10000 Password combinations possible.

Now after each trial the chance for a successful guess increases by a slight percentage because we just tried one password and now we remove that password from the "guessing set". That being said I am struggling with the actual calculation.

I first calculate the probability of me NOT guessing the password and then subtract that from 1.

\begin{align}
       1-\frac{9999}{10000} \cdot \frac{9998}{10000} \cdot \frac{9997}{10000} = 0.059\%
     \end{align}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple approach is that there are $10000$ possible PINs and you have tried $3$ of them, so your chance of finding the right one is $\frac 3{10000}$.  In your calculation, the denominators should decrease $10000,9999,9998$, so you will get the same result.$$1-\frac {9999}{10000}\cdot \frac {9998}{9999}\cdot\frac{9997}{9998}=1-\frac {9997}{10000}=\frac 3{10000}$$

Comment: Oh I feel so stupid now, yes of course, the 10000 should decrease by 1 each time as the number of combinations now took a hit because we tried one, thank you !

Answer (score 4):

In the second trial, there are $9998$ ways out of $9999$ ways we can miss the right pin.

$$1-\frac{9999}{10000}\cdot \frac{9998}{9999}\cdot \frac{9997}{9998}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying $3$ different PINS, the chances of one of them being correct is $$\frac{3}{10000}$$